App must target Android 14 (API level 34) or higher -> Even after all the solutions given online it is not working in React Native
Google asked that the app must target Android 14 (API level 34) or higher.
I am trying to upgrade from API level 33 to 34 on React Native but unable to do so. I have tried many solutions given online but failed to upgrade properly.
I have already tried changing to
buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0" minSdkVersion = 23 compileSdkVersion = 34 targetSdkVersion = 34
also just tried changing
targetSdkVersion = 34
The app compiles but without opening, it closes on the emulator.
And when I create an apk, it runs on the phone but closes when the app tries to read the SMS on the phone or register a background task.

so look at what the error is

I'd take a look at what has changed for apps targeting Android 14 (API level 34): https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14

You need to share the exception/logs of what happens when you run your application on a device/emulated device with API 34. Otherwise, it will be hard to help you.

Update minSdkVersion to 24 and update the required plugin.
